using wave motion to raise mass INSIDE a ship?
As a ship bobs up and down, can a pulley INSIDE the ship raise a large mass?
     |       |              | xxxxx |
     |       |              | xxxxx |
  ~~~| xxxxx |~~~   ==>  ~~ |       |~~
     | xxxxx |              |       |
     +-------+              +-------+
 

Presumably, at the top of the crest, when the ships begins a downwards motion, a pulley can reel in the cable and "pull up" the mass relative to the ship hull, when in fact, the mass is vertically stationary?
(As a side note, I assume the mass can later be dropped and some of the energy is recovered. And yes - both wave and gravitational energy are very low density - this cannot compete with a liquid energy source)
EDIT: also depending on wave size, the downwards acceleration may be less than g=9.8 ? so maybe separate cases to consider

Can it? probably yes. Is it worth it? No.

Yes, mount the mass on a bouncy spring and fit a ratchet. If the ship is being propelled this will increase the power needed to drive the ship at a given speed. If the ship is stationary you have just created a rather inefficient form of wave powered generator, such as https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-07-31/wave-power-generator-supplying-king-island-with-electricity/101282070
